# XAMPP WordPress permissions on macOS

Tags: wordpress, macos, xampp, wordpress-theming

I'm using WordPress with XAMPP on macOS. I noticed that I can not change some theme files (style.css file of my theme) because I don't have permissions.

I tried changing the permissions and ownership of that file with `chmod` and `chown` respectively. But I can not do that because both commands fail with a message that I'm not "allowed".

How can an administrator of a system not be able to do a change like this?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! try to paste the *logs* of your errors so people can try and help you.

Comment: Try Local by Flywheel instead of XAMPP it is a much better environment.